# Using Apple Numbers, is there a way to display the difference between two dates in years, with decimals?

Tags: date, numbers, decimal, difference

I am simply trying to display the difference between to dates, but have the result contain a decimal.  For example, for the two dates 8/1/2009 and 7/6/2010, I would like a return of about "0.9" or something like that.  I can get the 339 days result by simply subtracting one cell from another, but when I use "Y", it only gives whole numbers.  Of course the date format boxes under the Cell section of the format and options are there, but they infuriatingly stop at "Week" and don't offer months or years.  I don't want, for example, "10 months, 25 days".  I'd really like it to simply be years with decimals, like "1.5" years instead of x amount of weeks or months. Any help appreciated..thanks.

Comment: Subtract one date from the other, take the total days from the result, and divide it by 365.

Comment: Yea, that doesn't work. In Apple Numbers, when you subtract one date from another, the result cell automatically gets formatted to a W,D, HR, Min, Sec, etc, NOT a simple "number" format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after the `YEARFRAC` function:

> Finds the fraction of a year represented by the number of whole days between two dates

Alternatives can also be found in the `DATEDIF` function, which allows you to return the result in a number of different units, but I'll let you read around that for yourself.

Comment: YEARFRAC was exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectly. Thanks!